# Network usage is always showing 0% in task manager

Tags: networking, windows-11, task-manager

I have been facing this issue that the Task manager is always showing the Network utilization percentage as 0% even though I'm using it, this problem starts some days before only before that it worked well I don't know what happened, Some one please help me to fix this issue, I have attached the snapshot of my problem. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WavrI.png)

Comment: What you are looking at is by specific process and at a moment in time, so not surprising. I see that as well.  Look in the performance tab and in that tab, your network. You should see the graph build as you use the network. Does this work?

Comment: If you want a more readily available graph, I use **Network Meter** from [Add Gadgets](https://addgadgets.com/)

Comment: What you are seeing is a long term issue affecting Windows 10 and 11. I posted a more complete answer

Comment: What do you mean with `I'm using it`? Are you just downloading something from WWW or are you really have a full-performance end-to-end copy process between two endpoints in your local network? Downloading something from WWW will most often not affect your local network adapter utilizations, e.g. you have a 25 Mbit/s internet connection but your PC network adapter has negotiated a 2.5 Gbit/s (=2560 Mbit/s) link speed with your router (→ 0.97% usage)

Comment: "I'm using it " means that I'm accessing the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the **Windows Network Data Usage** (NDU) monitoring driver is running, which is responsible for reporting your data usage and displaying it in the Task Manager.

To turn it on:

1. Open the Registry Editor and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Ndu`
2. Modify the **Start** registry to the value of **2 hexadecimal**.
3. Reboot the system.

Or simply open the Command Prompt and enter the following command:

```
Set-ItemPropertyVerified -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Ndu" -Name "Start" -Type DWord -Value 2
```

Comment: Wow !!!! I have no words to express you have solved my issues that existed for years, your solution worked for me thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 1):

Search for Task Manager, Process Tab, Network column. All the posts show and say the values are 0. Windows 10 too.

So this is "by design" - apparently a bad design.

Look in the Performance Tab and Network will show a working graph of network usage.

If you wish to see network usage by process, use Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and network usage shows up there.

What I report above is true for Windows 11 (all machines) and Windows 10 (VM).